# How to make a view between Spacers always at the center in an HStack?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

What I would like to achieve. regardless the width of text width at both side the button should always at the center of the `HStack`.

[image]

```
HStack {
    Text("Foooooooo")
    Spacer(minLength: 5)
    Button(action: { }) {
        Text("Bar")
    }
    Spacer()
    Text("Baz")
}
.font(.system(size: 16, weight: .heavy, design: .rounded))
.padding()
```

[image]

I also tried to use `GeometryReader` and set frame size for each `Text` and `Button` in the view however there are two problems,

1. The view returned by `GeometryReader` would occupies the entire view the parent offers to it instead of the actual intrinsic content size, the space only enough for `Text`, `Spacer` and `Button`
2. String inside the first `Text` could not be left align so does the string inside the last `Text` couldn't be right aligned

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here is possible approach for your case. Demo prepared & tested with Xcode 12 / iOS 14

[image: demo]

```
    HStack {
        Spacer()
            .overlay(Text("Foooooooo"), alignment: .leading)

        Button(action: { }) {
            Text("Bar")
        }

        Spacer()
            .overlay(Text("Baz"), alignment: .trailing)
    }
    .font(.system(size: 16, weight: .heavy, design: .rounded))
    .padding()
```

Comment: An overlay on a spacer, very clever!

Answer (score 10):

You want to layout three flexible-but-same-sized elements, but you have three fixed-but-differently-sized elements. To fix that, put each element in its own flexible stack (HStack w/ spacer) so that each get 1/3 of the space. Within each stack, use Spacers to align.

```
    HStack {
        // Left stack
        HStack {
            Text("Foooooooo")
            Spacer()
        }

        // Center stack. The surrounding Spacers aren't really required in this
        // specific case, but added for consistency and to show how to center.
        HStack {
            Spacer()
            Button(action: { }) {
                Text("Bar")
            }
            Spacer()
        }

        // Right stack
        HStack {
            Spacer()
            Text("Baz")
        }
    }
    .font(.system(size: 16, weight: .heavy, design: .rounded))
    .padding()
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to do it which is pretty concise and uses a `ZStack` to combine the centered button with an `HStack` with a single `Spacer` to push the labels to the edges:

```
ZStack {
    HStack {
        Text("Foooooooo")
        Spacer()
        Text("Baz")
    }
    Button(action: { }) {
        Text("Bar")
    }
}
.font(.system(size: 16, weight: .heavy, design: .rounded))
.padding()
```

**Note:** This solution works *if* you know your labels won't encroach on your button.  @Asperi's solution causes extra long labels to be truncated with `...`.  @RobNapier's solution causes extra long labels to wrap at 1/3 of the width.