# SwiftUI Add view next to other centered view

Tags: layout, swiftui

I have such case

```
VStack(alignment: .center) { 

  HStack { 
     Text("Title text")
     if shouldDisplayImage {
        Image(systemName: "dot")
     }
  }

  Text("Description text")
}
```

But I want to have both texts in VStack centered horizontally
and image that is sometimes displayed and sometimes hidden to be next to title text

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/60711100/12299030?

Comment: It seems to work but it is very complicated solution

Comment: Possible alternate is to use `Spacer`/s (or `Color.clear`) with overlays like in https://stackoverflow.com/a/63755614/12299030.

Comment: Yeah it is much simpler, and I've tested it works ok

Answer (score 1):

[image]

As Asperi suggested we can use .overlay() on Spacer()